# if statement to check other rows - Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, cell, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet along this format:

```
------------------------------------------------
|     A   |      B     |    C       |   D       |   
------------------------------------------------
|  type   |   wins     |    loss    |   ratio   |
------------------------------------------------
| cat     |     1      |            |     1     |
------------------------------------------------
| dog     |     2      |            |     2     |
------------------------------------------------
| rabbit  |            |      1     |     -1     |
------------------------------------------------
| dog     |     1      |            |     1     |
------------------------------------------------
| horse   |     1      |            |     1     |
------------------------------------------------
| dog     |            |      2     |     -2    |
------------------------------------------------
```

What I want, is to check if the "A" column contains the word "dog" and if it does count the amount of times it has won in the table.

So, the formula would output:

**dog total wins: 2**

As it won the first time it appeared in the table and the second time it won too. If there is a winner the loss cell will be empty, and visa versa. I don't need it to add up the wins and give me the total sum.

**Then**, as a second part, I need it to give me the average ratio for "dog", so the formula needs to check if the "A" column contains "dog", if it does, it needs to add up all the "dog" ratios and divide by how many there are.

I have the formula to add up how many times "dog" appears, but the rest I'm stumped on!

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A;"dog")
```

Can anyone advise of the correct formula please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

FIRST PART:

=counta(filter(B:B,A:A="dog"))

SECOND PART:

=sum(filter(D:D,A:A="dog"))/countif(A:A;"dog")

Hope this helps.